# Angular, test, dependency injection, http.get ... Help to understand

Tags: angular, http, dependency-injection, jasmine, karma-jasmine

First sorry for my english.

I'm using Angular and develop a simple service with his test.

The service load a JSON file with http.get method and store it content in a variable. 
The aim is not important.

Below a code that works :

First the service

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Constants} from 'config/constants';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LoadJsonFileService {
  private config: Object = null;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  private loadJsonAndUpdateConfig() {
    this.http
      .get(Constants.CONFIG_FILE_NAME)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch((error: any): any => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }).subscribe((configJson) => {
        this.config = configJson;
      });
  }
  public getConfig(key: string): string {
    if (!this.config) {
      this.loadJsonAndUpdateConfig();
    }
    return this.config[key];
  }
}
```

Then the test :

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, RequestOptions, Response, ResponseOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {LoadJsonFileService} from './load-json-file.service';
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('Test suite ...', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
        {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
        Http,
        LoadJsonFileService
      ]
    });
  });

  it('The test ...', inject([ConnectionBackend, LoadJsonFileService],
    (backend,
     service: LoadJsonFileService) => {
      backend.connections.subscribe((c: MockConnection) => {
        c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: {key: 'foo'}})));
      });

      expect(service.getConfig('key')).toBe('foo');
    }));

});
```

Test is **OK**.

The code that don't work and i don't know why :

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Constants} from 'config/constants';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class LoadJsonFileService {
  private config: Object = null;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.loadJsonAndUpdateConfig();
  }

  private loadJsonAndUpdateConfig() {
    this.http
      .get(Constants.CONFIG_FILE_NAME)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch((error: any): any => {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }).subscribe((configJson) => {
        this.config = configJson;
      });
  }
  public getConfig(key: string): string {
    return this.config[key];
  }
}
```

The difference is the call of this.loadJsonAndUpdateConfig() in the constructor and not in the getConfig method.
Test fail :

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.config[key]')
```

When I put some debug the subscribe method is never trigger like if http.get is never call ...

I'm confused is anyone can explain me this behaviour ?

Thanks,

Stef

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, just assign default value to variable

```
private config: Object = {};
```

Long version: first code example also shouldn't work, unless you assign something to `config` variable somewhere or backend request finishes before `this.config[key]` piece is executed (race condition), but if that works locally (or in tests), it may break on server.

Basically, `getConfig()` is called (I assume in template) before `this.config = configJson;`. Http requests are "async", i.e. js/ts/angular don't wait until it is completed, subsequent code is executed right after http request has been initiated.

If you want to test it, add async timeout before returning value, or better see angular documentation on `InMemoryWebApiModule`

Comment: thanks but the question was not why the null error (this is a consequence), my code is only to illustrate the question : why the `http.get` method is not called when the `loadJsonAndUpdateConfig()` method is called in the constructor but called when I put it in the `getConfig` method ?